# Why is my UISearchDisplayController accessing an illegal cell / indexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a table view with a search bar. Initially, the table view shows all (10) items. When I select a cell, a detail view is pushed on the navigation controller stack, and I can then go back to the table view by tapping the Back button. As long as I have not entered a search text yet, the table view shows all items, and I can go back and forth between the detail view and the table view indefinitely.

When I enter a text in the search bar, the table view is updated correctly with the self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView (say it only shows 8 items now), that means

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**is called 8 times (section 0, rows 0 to 7).** Fine.

I can then tap a cell, see the detail view, and go back to the table view showing the 8 items.

If I then select a cell in the table view still showing the 8 items (the same cell as before or a different one, does not matter), I again see the detail view, and then tap the "Back" button,

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**is called for section 0, row 8**, which is not existing, since the `searchResultsTableView` still only shows the 8 items (rows 0 to 7) from the search.

I don't really understand what is going on:

- the search works correctly,
- but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called with a "wrong" indexPath

EDIT: Removed assumption about mixing up the two table views - everything seems to be in the correct place, but cellForRowAtIndexPath is still called for row 8. Also note that it's ALWAYS row 8.

EDIT 2: Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath. "Zeichen" is a DAO, the getZeichenForIndexPath:indexPath returns the correct instance from the search result.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell" ];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell"];
    }

    Zeichen *zeichen = [self getZeichenForIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:zeichen.filename];
    cell.imageView.image = img;

    cell.textLabel.text = [zeichen description];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track (about mixing up the two table views). Make sure that you return correct number of rows for each of the both UITableViews in - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: I checked again - what I did mix is calling performSegue manually only for a selection in the searchDisplayController, and in the storyboard for the "normal" table view. I fixed this now, but the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is still called for an illegal row.

Comment: You need to post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code.

Comment: @thomers  This method looks fine.  What does `tableView numberOfRowsInSection:` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should control `tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`. This control should be in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method as well.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
      {
             UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell" ];
             if (cell == nil) {
                  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell"];
             }
      }
      else
      {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" ];
             if (cell == nil) {
                  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
             }
      }
    return cell;
}
```

other thought: `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]` usage is more convenient, if you are initialize your table view in storyboard or nib (setting cell identifier in storyboard).

Comment: THanks, indeed I ended up checking for the correct table view in all the relevant methods.